# PHP resort keys from multidimensional array

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

i have a multidimensional array whose index/keys (not the values) are like this:

this is how the submitted array looks

```
  [param] => Array
            (
                [3] => groupedlista
                [0] => groupedlistb
                [2] => groupedlistc
            )

        [f_name] => Array
            (
                [3] => grouplistaa
                [0] => grouplistbb
                [2] => grouplistcc
            )

        [f_label] => Array
            (
                [3] => grouplistL3
                [0] => grouplistL0
                [2] => grouplistL2
            )
```

this is how the order looks

```
0,2,3
```

i want that Result

```
  [param] => Array
            (
                [0] => groupedlistb
                [1] => groupedlistc
                [2] => groupedlista
            )

        [f_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => grouplistbb
                [1] => grouplistcc
                [2] => grouplistaa
            )

        [f_label] => Array
            (
                [0] => grouplistL0
                [1] => grouplistL2
                [2] => grouplistL3
            )
```

that's it

PS: i use a jquery sort / add / delete feature in the form and i prefer to do the final sorting php-based. the index array [$i] is required to be declared at the form.

Comment: please include a `print_r()` type output of what you have at the moment, and one of how you want it to end up.

Comment: Also, can you please post the code you tried with `usort`?

Comment: @daverandom i added the result code

Comment: and here I wanted to know why a PHP array had keys to a resort :)

Comment: @warren see the PS: part i wrote in the question. the resort/delete jquery function needs a "already in the form declared index" to work. otherwise the index would be automatically submitted onsubmit in the correct order and i wouldn't have the problem described.

Comment: @Email - puns are lost in the written word ... I read it as "resort" with a "z" for the "s", like a vacation destination :)

Comment: @warren puns rarely hit with people like me who are non-english speakers. since your words are too high for me i escape and say thanks for delighting this case with your exquisite puns :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$order = '0,2,3';

$out = array(); // This will hold the sorted values
$order = explode(',',$order); // Turn the order into an array
foreach ($multiDimArray as $key => $subArray) { // Loop outer array
  foreach ($order as $pos) { // Loop order array
    if (isset($subArray[$pos])) { // Make sure the key exists
      $out[$key][] = $subArray[$pos]; // Put the correct value in the correct place
    }
  }
}

print_r($out);
```